# How to query inside a column containg JSON array in postgres db

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres db. In that table I have a column containing JSON array

```json
{
            "DeviceId": "12355",
            "Message": {
                        "Test1": [{"Name": "1"}, {"Result": "Pass"}],
                        "Test2":[{"Name": "2"}, {"Result": "Fail"}],
                        "Test3": [{"Name": "3"}, {"Result": "Pass"}],
                        
            }
}
```

I need to query inside this and I want my output to be in below format.

```
DeviceID     Name   Result  
  "12355"    "1"   "Pass"     
  "12355"    "2"   "Fail" 
  "12355"    "3"   "Pass"
```

Following is the query which I tried

```
select DeviceId, Message  -> 'Name' as name, Message  -> 'Result' as Result from table
```

The result was not as expected

I'm new to postgres DB can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `deviceid` a column in the table or part of the JSON?

Comment: Its a part of JSON

Comment: What if an array contains `[{"Name": "1"}, {"Result": "Pass"}, {"Name": "2"}, {"Result": "Pass"}, {"Name": "3"}, {"Result": "Fail"}]`

Comment: @Anu Thanks for accepting, please upvote as well, I'd appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca5008b0e5622d0a91e50acc994ec377)

```
SELECT
    mydata ->> 'DeviceId' as device_id,
    tests.value -> 0 ->> 'Name' as name,
    tests.value -> 1 ->> 'Result' as result
FROM mytable,
    json_each(mydata -> 'Message') as tests
```

You can extract all data from `Message` into one row per element using `json_each()`. Afterwards you can access the array elements.

However, your structure seems not very well designed. Instead of

```
"Test1" : [{"Name": "1"}, {"Result": "Pass"}]
```

you should think of

```
"Test1" : {"Name": "1", "Result": "Pass"}
```

Comment: A well designed database would not use JSON for such data.

Comment: That comes on-top! ;)